# Problem regarding fluid domain

Tags: modeling

While using blender for making water simulation,when I set the physics of cube to fluid domain the cube still remains soild so I cannot see my water simulator unless I turn the wireframe mode on . I cannot figure out the problem . Please help me !

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Mesh" and press "Bake Mesh". This will create a mesh based on the information generated by the fluid data bake. What you are seeing now is only a particle system helping you visualize the fluid and is not meant to actually be used in a finished product.

After baking the mesh is finished, the domain will take on the shape of the liquid, and you will no longer need to use wireframe mode.

[image]